# Nested Async/Await Doesn't Appear To Be Scaling

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I have the following (simplified) code:

```
public async Task GetData(DomainObject domainObject, int depth)
{
  // This async operation is really quick, and there's usually like five.
  IEnumerable<TierOne> tierOnes = await domainObject.GetTierOnesAsync();

  var tierOneTasks = tierOnes.Select(async tierOne => 
  {
    // This async operation is really quick and there's usually like three.
    IEnumerable<TierTwo> tierTwos = await tierOne.GetTierTwosAsync();

    if (depth <= TierTwoDepth)
      return;

    var tierTwoTasks = tierTwos.Select(async tierTwo => 
    {
      // This async operation is usually fast, and there's usually >= 100.
      IEnumerable<TierThree> tierThrees = await tierTwo.GetTierThreesAsync();

      if (depth <= TierThreeDepth)
        return;

      var tierThreeTasks = tierThrees.Select(async tierThree => 
      {
        // This async operation is SLOW, and there's usually.. 50?
        await tierThree.GetTierFoursAsync();
      });

      await Task.WhenAll(tierThreeTasks.ToArray());
    });

    await Task.WhenAll(tierTwoTasks.ToArray());
  });

  await Task.WhenAll(tierOneTasks.ToArray());
}
```

Based off of what I have seen, it does not seem to be scaling very well. All of the `Async` operations are "true async" operations meaning that they are all I/O.

Am I using Async/Await incorrectly for this scenario? Based off of my current observations, it isn't scaling to what I would expect. Would TPL DataFlow be my solution?

Comment: "it seems to be scaling very well" is that a typo and you ment to put a `not` in there? And if so, scaling in what way, do you expect it to finish faster or just not put as much load on the system? How are you testing the scaling?

Comment: You are using a lot of `IEnumerables` as async return values. Are you sure that deferred exectution does not interfere with your assumed parallelisation?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes that was a typo. I'm expecting it to finish faster. I understand that it's only going to be going as fast as the receiving end of my async operations is going to process. It just seems that if I spool up 1500 tasks, I'd expect more than just 3 or 4 to be stuck in the `Await` portion of the state machine. (Sorry if this doesn't make any sense. It's late here, and I'm very sleepy.)

Comment: @nvoigt That's just the return type. The actual enumerables are evaluated (using the `ToList()` extension method) prior to returning to the calling method.

Comment: Async does not make it faster, in fact it usually makes it a little slower compared to the synchronous version of the same code due to the overhead, what it does for you is allow higher loads before you start to get performance drops.

Comment: @Cameron: Since your methods are all doing I/O (presumably against the same server), double-check your `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` setting. Or just set it to `int.MaxValue` at startup and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I understand that; I guess I'm just expecting some a greater degree of concurrency than what I seem to be getting. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @StephenCleary Looks like it was set to `2` by default. I tried jacking it up to `200`. You were correct in your guess about hitting the same server. I'll test it out later. I'd prefer to have it appear as though I'm (not so distributed) DDOS'ing the service that I'm hitting. My next best guess is that they're limiting the number of connections per consuming IP.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: It's short of an unofficial standard that clients (browsers, applications,etc) shouldn't make more than two HTTP requests to the same domain.  A far better implementation though would be to use an ActionBlock with eg 10 concurrent tasks so that you have control on the number of concurrent requests, even if you have 100 URLs to hit. Better yet, you can have one block per tier with different DOP settings, feeding their results to the next tier

Answer (score 0):

For a single call to `GetData`, nested async/await calls won't introduce any concurrency. You retrieve all tierOnes, then all the tierTwos for tierOne-#1, then all the tierThrees for tierTwo-#1, and so on, all run in sequence (though there may be some concurrency inside the GetTier*Async methods).

If you want concurrent requests, then TPL Dataflow is indeed a better solution.

Comment: I do not think that this is the case. All the tasks in one level are started (correctly) independently (because of the **Select** methods, and "awaited" by the **WhenAll** methods later). The concurrency is not introduced by async/await but the fact that LINQ is used to create the tasks. The only thing I can think of is that he simply runs out of threads, it happens in case you are dealing with nested async operations (it is almost like a recursion that obviously stops after a few levels - but not before draining out the thread pool).

Comment: @Miklós As the OP writes, his `GetAsync` methods are true async I/O, so they don't block any thread while they run. I ran `GetData` (with `Task.Delay` calls) from a `DispatcherSynchronizationContext`, and there's no concurrency, so the thread pool cannot limit performance. Running `GetData` from a null synchronization context does introduce concurrency, but if the I/O to the server is slower than the send/receive code (as the OP describes), the bottlenecks in the thread pool are a tiny percent of the total wait time. His bottleneck was probably somewhere else (like Stephen Cleary suggested).